# UIActionSheet buttons lack visual feedback in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, uiactionsheet

I am seeing a small (but really annoying) difference between iOS 7 and 8 concerning UIActionSheet.  In iOS 7, the button that the user taps in the action sheet is selected **immediately**, giving prompt visual feedback of which button was pressed.  (By "selected" I mean the background color of the button changes.)  However, in iOS 8 the button does not visually appear selected unless the user taps and holds an action sheet button.  Since a normal tap is typically very brief (and not held), this has the effect of the button usually never looking selected in an iOS 8 action sheet.

What the user sees after tapping Option 2 in iOS 8: no selected button as the dialog does its close animation.

[image]

If the user taps and holds Option 2, the button finally appears selected.  This is also what the user would see **immediately** after tapping in iOS 7.

[image]

UIActionSheet usage:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                   initWithTitle:nil 
                   delegate:self 
                   cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                   otherButtonTitles:@"Option 1...", @"Option 2", @"Option 3", @"Option 4",
                   nil];
[actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem: myView.optionsButton animated: YES];
```

Please note that the action sheet otherwise functions as expected.  The appropriate action call is made, etc.  *The issue is only the lack of visual feedback of the button press.*

I know that UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8, however, I have tried using UIAlertController with the same results.  This seems to be an OS-wide user interface decision.

In iOS 7, there is immediate visual feedback when tapping an option in an action sheet.  Is there anyway to get this behavior back in iOS 8?

Edit: The action sheet button in Mail in iOS 8 demonstrates the behavior.  This is the Reply/Forward/Print button.  Tapping an option does not give visual feedback, but tapping and holding the option does.

Comment: well if it is in mail too then Id say it is a bug/deliberate change ;) file a report and if you really think it is bad, roll your own menu component